# How to implement AWS API GATEWAY OPTIONS method authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to implement Authentication in OPTIONS method(preflight request ) in AWS using lambda authorizers but I am getting 401 error.

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly and specifically. Please add your problematic code to see what is happening.

Comment: Is it a good idea to for OPTIONS requests to be authenticated?

Comment: I don't believe `OPTIONS` is supposed to be authenticated and it is probably a violation of the spec for the browser to supply credentials even if they're solicited by a (misconfigured) server.  What's your motivation, here?